# Can't sign_in with overridden Devise SessionControl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm working on Rails 5 application (api only), I use Devise for the `User` model, with control overridden at `mobile/auth/users`. I can use only few actions of each controller, for example I can `sign_up` via `cURL` but I can't `sign_in`, I don't know why. Here there's the example:

Controller: `sessions: 'mobile/auth/users/sessions'`

Overriding example:

```
def create
    super
end
```

Request:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://api.test.com:3000/mobile/users/sign_in -d '{"user" : { "email" : "user@example.com", "password" : "1234567890"}}'
```

Error: `401 Unauthorized`

Body: `{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}`

I'm trying to sign_in and I'm already signed up with correct confirmation, why with controller overriding nothing works? In normal application with views all goes well.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** full controller

```
 class Mobile::Auth::Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

   # GET /resource/sign_in
   # def new
   #   super
   # end

   # POST /resource/sign_in
   def create
       super
   end

   # DELETE /resource/sign_out
   def destroy
     super
   end

   protected

   # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
   def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:password])
   end

   def serialize_options(resource)
     super
   end

   def auth_options
     super
   end

   def translation_scope
     super
   end

   private

   # Check if there is no signed in user before doing the sign out.
   #
   # If there is no signed in user, it will set the flash message and redirect
   # to the after_sign_out path.
   def verify_signed_out_user
     super
   end

   def all_signed_out?
     super
   end

   def respond_to_on_destroy
     super
   end
 end
```

**EDIT v2**

Ok, so, the problem is that *I CAN'T LOGIN VIA CURL WITH DEVISE*. Even if I put cookie with `-b cookie_name` I get always `401 Status Code`. Devise by default use cookies to handle "session" (nothing on server side). How to migrate devise behaviour on server side with `session`? Should I write my own code or is possible to change behaviour by using yet devise?

Comment: Hi. Can you show us the rest of your new SessionsController please? :)

Comment: It has nothing more that all methods with `super` keyword as explained in the question, I override controllers in order to give custom message in the future, but nothing now. I really don't know what goes wrong. No `before_filter`, no `after_filter`, nothing more that original devise controller.

Comment: if it literally has nothing more... then that is a problem ;)
I was hoping to see any filters, and also the sub-classing... can you please show it? Stack Overflow works best with that old author's adage: "Show don't tell" - don't tell me there's nothing more to see... prove it by showing us ;)

Comment: Kewl thanks :)
So - can you add a debug statement in your `create` action to make sure you're actually getting to it? It's plausible that your code is bailing out somewhere else (in a before filter) that could have nothing to do with this code... Also I notice: `http://api.test.com:3000/mobile/users/sign_in` and yet `Mobile::Auth::Users::SessionsController` -> what exactly does your routes file say for this route?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. By debug, call is performed and issue is about namespacing in routes. Now, what about overriding controllers two times for the same recource class? How to setup routes? with `scope` and `module` I get error because there are doubled `Prefix`. **I need to override two times for the same `User` resource the devise controller.** Should I setup all routes by hand or there's a way to use **`devise_for`**?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to override two times for the same User resource the devise controller." what are you overriding? What do you actually have for the route? edit your question and show us what you've actually tried in your code (and the error messages that you get) Show don't tell :)

Comment: Sorry, please look for updated question. The error is that devise don't store the session. I get cookie but cookie is never accepted even if I use -b option for curl.